# Python: avoid __setattr__ loop using __dict__, shouldn't it loop anyway?

Tags: python, loops, setattr

I know that you should be aware while redefine **setattr** method that you could end in a loop.

I know there's two solution to avoid loops:

1) using object superclass, calling :

```
object.__setattr__(instance,attr,value)
```

2)  using the class dict:

```
self.__dict__[attr] = value
```

My question is, shouldn't the `__dict__` solution end up in a loop too? and why it isn't?

Is because that way we're calling the `__setattr__` of the `__dict__` object (everything is an object) or what?

And if so, shouldn't it work the same for everything?

Comment: `a[b] = c` doesn't set an attribute. It sets an item. It's a different thing both conceptually and w.r.t. dunder methods involved.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why would you expect it to end up in a loop?

`instance.__dict__[attr] = value` is basically what `object.__setattr__(instance,attr,value)` does (for normal attributes).  Note that `__dict__[attr] = whatever` **does not call `__setattr__` at all.**  It calls **`__setitem__`** which is a different method entirely.

Comment: It also calls it on an entirely different object.

Comment: @delnan -- True.  Of course, using `__getattribute__` you can get into the infinite loop using `self.__dict__`, but ...

Comment: So it is because is calling __setitem__ or because is a different object? thanks guys